# Rxjava2 how to return result from previous node to the next node in the chain succinctly

Tags: node.js, firebase, promise, rx-java2

I use rxjava2 in android,sometimes I meet a problem like this:

```java
Observable.fromArray(
         // maybe a list about photo url in SDCard
    )
    .flatMap(
         // make list to single and upload to server,
         // use retrofit observable<uploadResponse>
    )
    .map(uploadResponse -> {
        // *Problem of point
    })
    .map(
        // in this map I want to get this single photo url in SDCard
        // and some info from uploadResponse,how to do in 
        // *Problem of point of previous map?
     );
```

This code ignore some thread switch and other unimportant steps.This Problem also make me confusion in nodejs's Promise,how to pass some value to chain's  every step?I use nodejs's version6 on firebase,it not support await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for JavaScript part of the question, it's conveniently solved with `async..await`:

```
(async () => {
  const foo = await fooPromise;
  const bar = await getBarPromise(foo);
  const baz = await getBazPromise(bar);
})()
.catch(console.error);
```

> I use nodejs's version6 on firebase,it not support await.

The pattern behind `async..await` is widely used since the appearance of generators in Node 4. The same thing can be implemented with `co` which is most renowned implementation:

```
const co = require('co');

co(function * () {
  const foo = yield fooPromise;
  const bar = yield getBarPromise(foo);
  const baz = yield getBazPromise(bar);
})
.catch(console.error);
```

Since `async` function is syntactic sugar for promises, everything that `async` function does can be rewritten with promises alone.

Given there's a value that may be needed later (`foo`):

```
fooPromise
.then(foo => getBarPromise(foo))
.then(bar => getBazPromise(bar))
.then(baz => {
  // foo and baz are needed here
});
```

It should be either passed through the chain alongside with other results:

```
fooPromise
.then(foo => {
  return getBarPromise(foo).then(bar => ({ foo, bar }));
})
.then(({ foo, bar }) => {
  return getBazPromise(bar).then(baz => ({ foo, baz }));
})
.then(({ foo, baz }) => {
  // foo and baz are destructured from the result
});
```

Or promises should be nested in order for `foo` to be available within current function scope:

```
fooPromise
.then(foo => {
  return getBarPromise(foo)
  .then(bar => getBazPromise(bar))
  .then(baz => {
    // foo and baz are available here
  })
});
```

Same recipes are applicable to other APIs and languages. For instance, RxJS:

```
fooObservable
.flatMap(foo => Observable.zip(
  Observable.of(foo),
  getBarObservable(foo)
))
.map(([foo, bar]) => {
  // foo and bar are destructured from the result
})
```

Comment: My current code is the same idea as yours, but I think this way is similar to callback. If need to hold more values and pass more and more deeper levels(js's then or java's map) ,there will appear same thing as thatcallback hell.

Comment: In rxjava, I use the compose operator, which calls the wrap of the zip method(uploadResponse+pic local Url), but this usage can lead to a bad situation, such as my upload image function. When I wrap the upload of a single image, I need to add a zip return in it just for upload many pic function,but maybe other function only want to get uploadResponse,so my upload single pic func cannot be reused elsewhere

Comment: Several levels of nesting are less convenient but they are not nearly callback hell, because the latter means virtually unlimited levels of nesting. The thing that is specific to observables is that chain parts can be defined as variables and put together later because they aren't triggered before subscription, while this approach wouldn't work for promises. I'm not sure about RxJava but in RxJS 6 a pipeline can be extracted and be used as custom operator, `let customPipeline = pipe(map(...), map(...)); ...; observable.pipe(customPipeline)`. This eliminates nested callbacks.

Comment: Any way, these are the options here. You either nest a part of the chain or flatten the chain by passing data that is unused in some parts of the chain. It's up to you how efficiently you can reuse the code. In the code above it would be `.map(([foo, bar]) => [foo, mapFnThatNeedsBar(bar)])`.